# Pacserve is installed but it won't share files. What is wrong?

Tags: upgrade, pacman

I have three laptops all on the same 192.168.1.x local network
All have the most recent version of Arch installed and all have the most upto date packages installed.

All three have the `pacserv` package installed.

I have not had reliable success using pacserve to save bandwidth by sharing already downloaded packages on the local network. Sometimes one of the laptops gets blistering package sharing download speeds across the local gigabit network. But mostly this does not happen

On each laptop I have run the following command
`sudo systemctl start pacserve`

I update one with this command then once it is finished I run the same on the others to take advantage of the already downloaded packages
`sudo pacsrv -Syu`

It is not obvious to me what I am doing wrong.
I don't want to modify my pacman.conf file - perhaps I need to?
Do I need to put
`Include = /etc/pacman.d/pacserve`
under each repository/ source in `pacman.conf` on each of the machines, or do something else?

Answer (score 0):

### About Pacserve

Pacserve when it is running on each machine is just a simple web server.
You can see all the packages on each machine by browsing it using it's local IP address eg https://192.168.1.116:15678.

Pacserve shares files over http using port 15678 (not port 80 as is commonly used by http). Browsing to this port on your web browser from another machine is an easy way to see if the ports on the donor machine are open.

### The problem I had

was that after installation of pacserve

1. the broadcasting network ports were not open
2. Once all broadcasting network ports were open, on all laptops, upgrading laptops could not see or detect the open ports on the already upgraded computer that held all the new packages

This was fixed using the outlined steps below.

### Installation

- Firstly install `pacserv` with `yay -S pacserve`
- Secondly make sure  that python3-threaded_servers is installed with `yay -S python3-threaded_servers`
- Thirdly make sure that `/etc/pacserve/pacserve.service.conf` has `--avahi` network/port discovery service within it as follows
  `PACSERVE_ARGS="--multicast --avahi"`

### Bash Aliases for turning pacserve service and ports on & off

Next set up easy to use bash aliases that will allow you to

- enable and turn on and off the pacserve service and ports service
- and update and upgrade

You might want to define a `password_z="my password here"` variable in your `.bash_aliases`. Approve or dissaprove this is the way I do it.

`.bash_aliases` file additions for pacserve:

```
# turn pacserve on
alias        pson=echo $password_z | sudo -S systemctl start  pacserve.service; \
                  echo $password_z | sudo -S systemctl enable pacserve-ports.service; \
                  echo $password_z | sudo -S systemctl start pacserve-ports.service"

# turn pacserve off
alias      psoff="echo $password_z | sudo -S systemctl enable pacserve.service; \
                  echo $password_z | sudo -S systemctl stop   pacserve.service; \
                  echo $password_z | sudo -S systemctl enable pacserve-ports.service; \
                  echo $password_z | sudo -S systemctl stop   pacserve-ports.service"

# update and upgrade
alias   upgrade="echo $password_z | sudo -S systemctl enable pacserve.service; \
                 echo $password_z | sudo -S systemctl start  pacserve.service; \
                 echo $password_z | sudo -S systemctl enable pacserve-ports.service; \
                 echo $password_z | sudo -S systemctl start  pacserve-ports.service; \ 
                 yes | sudo -S pacsrv -Syu"


# check to see if pacserve is running and has opened the ports that allow it to share files
#   scroll to the bottom to see if the ports are open
alias    upgradej="echo $password_z | sudo -S journalctl -u pacserve"
```

then just before upgrading all laptops use alias `pacserveon` on all machines then upgrade one with
`sudo -S pacsrv -Syu`

then the other laptops on the LAN will upgrade with blistering speed  as packages are shared, also using `sudo -S pacsrv -Syu` on each machine after the first one has been upgraded.

Then after upgrading all laptops close the open ports with alias `pacserveoff`

You can check if your ports are open with
`journalctl -u pacserve`
scroll down to the bottom and you should see the broadcasting ports active after using `pacserveon`.

Contrast this with
`sudo systemctl stop pacserve.service`
and you will see the ports have all closed, which obviously stops the service working.

Over the internet I get package downloads at approximately 3Mbps normally for the first laptop. Second laptop using pacserve over LAN wired connection 100Mbps package download speeds, and 3rd laptop 7Mbps with pacserve over WiFi. So updating one box with pacserve them plugging other laptops all into ethernet cable is very advantageous.

### When all ports are open check they are open by browsing each laptops HTTP file server from another laptop

15678 is the port that pacserve shares files on, and pacserve is just a simple web server with package files on it that are made available for sharing.

So if you have, say three laptops, then after opening the pacserve ports on each you can check that the pacserve http server is running by browsing the server on each laptop as follows
https://192.168.1.116:15678
https://192.168.1.107:15678
https://192.168.1.109:15678

You will see the web page showing the package cache.

### Make sure that python3-threaded_servers is installed

This can be installed with `yay -S python3-threaded_servers`

If your istallation is not working and the ports are definatley open then re-install `python3-threaded_servers` with `yay -S python3-threaded_servers`
Reference    https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacserve

### Enable avahi mDNS/DNS-SD auto local network discovery

If your computers still cannot see each others file package cache over the LAN network then enable avahi auto local network discovery   .

If you use nvim as a text editor as I do then type
`sudo nvim /etc/pacserve/pacserve.service.conf`
and make sure the line
`PACSERVE_ARGS="--multicast"` is modified to
`PACSERVE_ARGS="--multicast --avahi"`